# Using Faker in Laravel 5.0 returns 'Class User not found'

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I am trying to put test data in a database for a Laravel project. I have followed the instructions on Laracasts, and a couple of sites. When I try to run my Seeder class, I get "Class 'User' not found"
Here is my class:

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

 class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

   public function run()
   {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
    {
        $user = User::create(array(
            'name' => $faker->userName,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'password' => $faker->word,
            'verified' => $faker-numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 1)
        ));
    }
    }
}
```

Does anyone out there know what I need to do?

Comment: you need to import your `User` class. `use App\User;`

Comment: don't worry, its normal when we work with namespaces (imports) without an ide that imports all for us, next time check if you import the classes that you're using xD

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is due to class mapping issue. Run the following command from your command line

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

If this does not work then Alternatively you can use namespace for your models. To this just define namespace in your User Modal

```
namespace Models;
```

To use This class just put the following line in your code

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Models\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
 $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

 for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
 {
     $user = User::create(array(
        'name' => $faker->userName,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => $faker->word,
        'verified' => $faker-numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 1)
    ));
 }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks all. The namespace issue pointed out by Carlos was the problem. He answered in teh comments, so I couldn't mark it as the answer....

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 namespace your models by default with the `App` namepace.
So you must refer to your `User` model as `App\User`

If you have changed the default namespace with

```
php artisan app:name YourNamespace
```

use the namespace you used instead of `App`

Answer (score 0):

```
use Models\User;
```

Should be:

```
use App\User;
```